# Что выбрать для программирования в Linux с помощью GTK, C или С++?

Tags: c, gtk, c++, linux

Хотелось бы услышать ответ в таком стиле:

какие преимущества у меня будут при написании объектно ориентированного кода с помощью *GTK* на *C* и какие недостатки, и соответственно так же и для *С++*?

Еще хотелось бы услышать предпочтения ваши.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Си не имеет средств для выражения объектов. С++ имеет. Как следствие - реализация объектной структуры на Си возможна, но будет что-то в духе WinAPI. Набор функций, набор данных. И можно будет нечаянно вызвать не ту функцию не для того 'объекта'.
С другой стороны, C++ дает возможность смело использовать Qt. А бОльшая часть ПО под Linux написана на C. И никто вроде особо не жалуется. Но нужно быть очень внимательным. Дабы не допускать 'глупых' ошибок. Сколько раз уже правили переполнения буферов :-)
Еще из неплохих графических библиотек есть wxWidgets. Очень похож на MFC и для адептов последнего переход на wxWidgets будет не так травматичен :-)

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим ответом. Добавлю что сами функции библиотеки GTK исполнены в старом добром виде обычных функций без какой либо объектной ориентированности.

Comment: То есть, основной недостаток Си, это "лишний" код и необходимость во внимательности?

Comment: До некоторой степени - да. Хотя в с++ тоже можно наворотить дров :-)

Answer (score 4):

Итак если сами не знаем, смотрим на опыт более опытных товарищей, итак: gnome написан на си, gimp написан на си, Dia написан на си, но тем не менее AbiWord написан на С++, в общем подавляющее большинство программ использующих gtk написано на си, но все же есть программы которые написаны либо в связке с другими языками либо на С++, поэтому что выбирать скорее зависит от конкретной задачи нежели от самой библиотеки.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае Си имеет следующее преимущество перед C++: Gtk-классы созданные с помощью Си можно использовать в скриптовых языках, предварительно написав связку, либо воспользовавшись [gtk gir](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gi/unstable/). Не уверен, но на C++ этого вроде вообще нельзя сделать.

Сложилась традиция в gnome/gtk среде писать на Си. Так получилось в первую очередь из-за более простого связывания со скриптовыми языками программ на Си.

Недостатки использования Си также есть: код выглядит довольно страшно, приходится писать дополнительный вспомогательный код.

*Оффтоп*: Если вы начинающий программист, то советую начать с Си, т.к. он меньше и проще C++, но не менее мощен.